# Bash to comment a line in LaTeX .cls file with %, using sed command

Tags: bash, sed, replace

I am trying to use bash with `sed` to replace this

```
    \printfield{year}%
```

by this

```
    %\printfield{year}%
```

There are 4 spaces at the start of the line (although I am not sure if this matters). Basically, this is a `LaTeX` `*.cls` file and I need to comment out every occurrence of `\printfield{year}%`.

My attempt was based on [this SO post](https://serverfault.com/a/399614/367989)

```
sed -i 's/\printfield{year}%/%\printfield{year}%/g' mydir/xxxxx.cls
```

however it produces this output

```
    \%printfield{year}%
```

where the `%` sign is in the wrong place - it should be at the start of the line (1st character), but it is appearing as the 2nd character. I also tried `sed -i "..."`.i.e. using double quotes, but it still gave the same wrong output (above) as single quotes.

Is there a way to comment out this line by placing a `%` at the beginning of the line, using `sed` in bash?

**System Info**

```
Ubuntu 18.10
```

Comment: your sed is just the same thing twice.

Comment: Apologies. Just updated it. I had `...{year}%/\printfield{year}...`, but it should have been `...{year}%/%\printfield{year}...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

backslash needs escaping

```
$ sed 's/\\printfield{year}%/%&/g' file
```

note that you don't have to repeat matched string again, `&` is for that.

Comment: I was not even looking at the original string, thinking the problem had nothing to do with that part of the command. Thanks! worked! And thank you for the explanation about `&` - this is a very helpful shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

`\p`

The `\` is an escape character. In order to print `\` you need to specify it twice. The `\p` escapes to just `p` and the `\` is ignored. Use:

```
sed 's/\\printfield{year}%/%\\printfield{year}%/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because bash is interpreting the \ character as an escape character, thus in your sed command

```
sed -i 's/\printfield{year}%/%\printfield{year}%/g' mydir/xxxxx.cls
```

its trying to replace escaped 'p' printfield with the other command, to get around this escape your `\` with another `\`

so

```
sed -i 's/\\printfield{year}%/%\\printfield{year}%/g' mydir/xxxxx.cls
```

Comment: Nice explanation. Thanks. I was thinking I had to escape the `%`, and so I tried it but it did not work. I didn't even think I had to escape the `\ `....that was key point I was missing.